# wpf - Select date range and generate column headers

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datepicker

Is it possible to select a date range using two datepickers? The first datepicker would represent the start date and second datepicker represents the end date.

Once those dates are selected, can datagrid columns be generated with the headers containing those dates?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgTemplate" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Employees, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.SelectedEmployee, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Mode=TwoWay}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True" DisplayMemberPath="EmpName" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignComboBox}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Employee Name"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <!--DataGridDateColumns-->

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deduction"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The commented section should be where the columns appear. The dates in the header should be in this format "dd/mm/yyyy", which can either be "Mon 01/Feb/2017" or "01/02/2017".

But the most important aspect I need would be the columns appearing once a range is selected.

Comment: Yes you can do it fairly easily in a variety of ways like creating a custom `DataGridBoundColumn` , or an `AttachedProperty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop, (for, while, etc) to iterate through the days within the range. Create and Add a new Column for each date.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
DateTime startDate = (DateTime)dtpStartDate.SelectedDate;
DateTime endDate = (DateTime)dtpEndDate.SelectedDate;

  if (startDate != null && endDate != null)
  {
      while (startDate < endDate)
      {
          DataGridTextColumn newColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
          newColumn.Header = startDate.ToShortDateString();

          dgTemplate.Columns.Add(newColumn);

          startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I place them at a specific index? Currently they appear at the end. **Edit** I just figured it out; `dgTemplate.Columns.Insert(1, newColumn);`

Comment: Glad I could help!